# Download SCORM from online course

Tags: scorm

I'm coursing a online formation. The contains are in SCORM format, the scorm reproduces at navigator. Exist any way to download the contains? I need view the contains after the course end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer: A SCORM content is usually a collection of many smaller files, which are loaded on demand from the web server, depending on the user's browsing through the content. So, just like anything else in the internet, as soon as you access the content, you have already downloaded it somewhere in your computer (where the browser stores temporary internet files). But that will only give you the parts of the content that you have already accessed, not the content as a whole.